# Test Explorer List in Visual Studio 2012 Extension VSIX

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, envdte, vsix, test-runner

I would like to retrieve the list of tests from the test explorer in a visual studio 2012 extension.

Is this possible using the Package.GetGlobalService or via DTE?

[Edit]
Since this is getting no response I'll provide some more info.

Currently IDE extensions or plugins, that wish to run solution tests do so by providing their own runners. Gallio is one such example of a test runner that has plugin to run multiple types of tests. Resharper is an example of an IDE extension that includes a test runner

VS2012 is introducing a new Test Runner which 3rd party test libraries can develop against such as nunit, xunit, qunit. With this change, it is possible to run these different types of tests within VS itself, namely via the 'Test Explorer' window.

For 3rd parties to interact with the IDE tests, it is necessary to be able to get a list of the tests, run the tests and receive the output of the tests.

So with that in mind, is there any access to the test interfaces in the VS 2012 IDE?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a good starting point:

[API Reference for Testing Tools for Visual Studio ALM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465178)

Comment: No, there is nothing about question theme